# How to enable download on my site hosted by GitHub.io?

Tags: html, github, server, download, hosting

On my site hosted by GitHub.io, I have a download button like the following:

```
<a href="link to the file" download>Download</a>
```

However, when I click on it, it redirects me to the page where the file is located. How do I enable download rather than redirecting?

Comment: Is the file located on the same site? For example,  `{your github url}}/{filename}`

Comment: @Shradha no, it is on another repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `download` attribute only works for `same-origin URLs`. So if the href is not the same origin as the site, it won't work.

In other words, you can only download files that belongs to that website.

[Here's](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/38-html-download-attribute/) a more detailed explanation of the same.